# (pdflib) Table of contents with dynamic page numbers

Tags: php, pdf-generation, pdflib

I'm on pdflib 7 under php5 and I'm drawing a statistical report with several sub topics over several pages.

Now, I want to include a table of contents on the first page where every sub topic is listed with it's actual page number. Needles to say that I don't know those page numbers at the time I draw the table of contents.

Is there a way to 'jump' back to the first page after drawing the rest of the document and creating the TOC knowing the actual page numbers for the sub topics?

tia for any hints or ideas

K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use suspend_page() and resume_page(). You might check out the PDFlib Cookbook:

http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/pagination/